# How to change index where .push() adds data in Firebase Realtimedatabase on Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using the firebase .push() creates a new child at the end of specified reference with a random key and then we can add data to it. However I want to add data in Between it . for example :

**If this is the initial case:**

```
{ 
    "-L7kYVU5-CxkqBCmJLO-" : {
    "articleCategory" : "tech",
    "articleText" : "Hi , today lets talk about android....",
    "articleTitle" : "new Android version announced",
    "articleUrl" : "www.somewebsite.com/android_article",
    "imgUrl" : "www.image.com"
  },
  "-L7kZozxhubLtJaOG1cy" : {
    "articleCategory" : "tech",
    "articleText" : "Apple Homepod - is the new product by Apple.....",
    "articleTitle" : "Apple HomePod",
    "articleUrl" : "www.somewebsite.com/apple_homepod",
    "imgUrl" : "www.someotherimage.com"
  }
}
```

**What I want-**

```
 { 
    "-L7kYVU5-CxkqBCmJLO-" : {
    "articleCategory" : "tech",
    "articleText" : "Hi , today lets talk about android....",
    "articleTitle" : "new Android version announced",
    "articleUrl" : "www.somewebsite.com/android_article",
    "imgUrl" : "www.image.com"
  },
{ 
    "-L7kYVU5-CxkqBOKAtO-" : {
    "articleCategory" : "tech",
    "articleText" : "The new iphone....",
    "articleTitle" : "Iphone X review",
    "articleUrl" : "www.somewebsite.com/iphoneX_article",
    "imgUrl" : "www.otherimage.com"
  },
  "-L7kZozxhubLtJaOG1cy" : {
    "articleCategory" : "tech",
    "articleText" : "Apple Homepod - is the new product by Apple.....",
    "articleTitle" : "Apple HomePod",
    "articleUrl" : "www.somewebsite.com/apple_homepod",
    "imgUrl" : "www.someotherimage.com"
  }
}
```

So basically I want to add a child between 2 existing ones with a randomkey(or any key) after the first child and not at the end of the list that usually happens using .push()

Using the orderByChild() method can be used to change the order in which the data is received that too in a particular ascending or descending order(I may be wrong about this but thats what I understood from the docs)

I dont know if it is possible , but if it is please help me or if its not is there any workaround to do this?

Comment: Please replace your pseudo data structure with the actual JSON that you have (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: done, I hope its clear now

Answer (score 2):

Push IDs are random, but also based on the time at which they were generated.  They will always sort in chronological order.  If you need to sort your records by some other criteria, use a child value.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I don't exactly want to sort, I just want to add data to a specific index for example 2(after 1) so whenever data is loaded it remains in the usual order but also has the newly added child in the desired position Is it possible? Maybe by adding a timestamp manually if yes how?

Comment: There is no index when using push IDs.  Child keys are always sorted alphabetically, which for push IDs is also chronologically.

Comment: So is there a way to insert a new child between two push ids using code?

Comment: No, please read my answer again to understand why every push ID will be added to the end (they are based on time and sort chronologically).

Comment: Alright thanks , is there any other possible method to achieve the desired result? U mentioned about child values how exactly do I use them to get what I need

Comment: In your initial pseudo data structure you gave the items an "index". You will need to add such an `index` property to each child node, and then use that to determine their explicit order. This all is unfortunately fairly non-trivial due to the fact that Firebase is meant to continue working when you're offline, and in highly concurrent multi-user situations. Using array-like indexes hurts for both of these. For a good intro to this, see https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html